# VBA do until loop code to copy range of cells to other range till same value

Tags: vba

I made a excel sheet where certain range of cells (J11 to J36) values are updated when value in the G1 is entered.

And, then values from J11 to J36 are manually entered (or copied) to D11 to D36.
By doing this, again values of J11 to J36 will get changed. SO, then I do iterative calculation to make both ranges same.

**Is there any macro code to automate this?**

I tried to do until loop but it only copies first range that is J11.

FYI, in range J11 to J36, in betwen there are title rows which are J19,J20,J28,J29 that should be skipped while copying.

My current code is below,

```
Sub DoUntilloop()

Dim i As Integer

i = 11
For i = 11 To 16


Do Until i > 16
Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 10)
i = i + 1
Loop

Next i

End Sub
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include your existing code in the question, so that we can work out what needs to be fixed.

Comment: Hi THanks for the response. Please find below for existing code.

Sub DoUntilloop()

Dim i As Integer

i = 11
For i = 11 To 16


Do Until i > 16
Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 10)
i = i + 1
Loop

Next i

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You current loop should actually be processing rows 11 to 16, not just 11 as you state in the question.  However, it is designed poorly, as there is no need to have two loops - the outer loop is effectively doing nothing as it is currently written.

```
Sub DoUntilloop()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 11 To 36
        If i <> 19 And i <> 20 And i <> 28 And i <> 29 Then
            Cells(i, "D").Value = Cells(i, "J").Value
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi YowE3K, You're right. I didn't notice that its actually process 11 to 16 rows. 
The reason why I added loop is to copy the values until both gets same value. As I mentioned, once J11 to J36 values are copied to D11 to D36, again J11 to J36 values will be changed (Due to another formula). both will get matched after some iterations. 
I guess that your code is now perfect to copy cells first time. 
But is it possible to make the cell values same? Any help from you will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sarathkumar Without knowing what values you are entering in G1, and how you determine each successive value, there is no way that I can think of to do this.  (It sounds like a job for Solver, but I can't be sure.)

Comment: The thing is I cant share the excel file or any other details due to confidentiality since I make this excel for office. So I can be little more elaborative in my request. Cell G1 is of temperature. So for each temperature I am trying to define a values which are J11 to J36. Also, from these values I am trying to match another set of values that is D11 to D36. values keeps on transferred to D11 to D36 until it becomes equal. What I did is I find the differences between both ranges after each paste. And If difference is 0 it can end.